# Conditional Graphing Plot?

Tags: wolframalpha

I am trying to graph two functions, but i want to graph one function for a condition but graph using another function if another condition is met.

A simple example would be:

if x > 0
then sin(x)
else cos(x)

It would then graph cos and sin depending on the x value, there being an obvious gap at x = 0, as cos(0) = 1 and sin(0) = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: There is a built-in way.  I'll leave my original answer below for posterity, but try using the piecewise() function:

```
plot(piecewise(((cos(x),x<0), (sin(x), 0<x))))
```

[See it here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28piecewise%28%28%28cos%28x%29%2Cx%3C0%29%2C%20%28sin%28x%29%2C%200%3Cx%29%29%29%29)

---

I would guess that there's a built-in way to do this, but I don't know it. You can multiply your functions by the [Heaviside Step Function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwiOjcDD5-jGAhXKN4gKHfuFDV4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHeaviside_step_function&ei=jXCsVc6SMsrvoAT7i7bwBQ&usg=AFQjCNGtSG4h-p9gjddb_e62WgUPUVbEdQ&sig2=t5p2WVMBi8EBlkU6KfRbZQ&bvm=bv.98197061,d.cGU&cad=rja) to accomplish this task.  The step function is 1 if x > 0 and 0 if x < 0, so multiplying this into your functions and then summing them together will select only one of them based on the sign of x, that is to say:

```
f(x) := heaviside(x) * sin(x) + heaviside(-x) * cos(x)
```

If x > 0, heaviside(x) = 1 and heaviside(-x) = 0, so f(x) = sin(x).

If x < 0, heaviside(x) = 0 and heaviside(-x) = 1, so f(x) = cos(x).

See it in action [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heaviside%28x%29*sin%28x%29%20%2B%20heaviside%28-x%29*cos%28x%29).  In general, note that if you want the transition to be at x = a, then you could do heaviside(x-a) and heaviside(-x+a), respectively.  If you want N functions, you'll have to have (N-1) multiplied step functions on each term, each with their own (x-a_i) argument. I hope someone else can contribute a cleaner solution.